# Type casting to pointer, precedence with addition

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion

```
#define GPIO_BASE 0x40020000
#define GPIO_MEM_SIZE 0x0400
```

Those are the macro definitions which will be related.

`GPIO_Type` is just a typedef struct I did.

```
volatile GPIO_Type *GPIOB = (GPIO_Type*) (GPIO_BASE + GPIO_MEM_SIZE);
```

This is fine, I am casting summation of two integers to the type of pointer I am defining.

If I do it as,

```
volatile GPIO_Type *GPIOB = GPIO_BASE + GPIO_MEM_SIZE;
```

Compiler gives a warning about "conversion from integer to pointer without casting". I understand this.

However, when I do,

```
volatile GPIO_Type *GPIOB = (GPIO_Type*) GPIO_BASE + GPIO_MEM_SIZE;
```

It(compiler) does not give a warning or error, but I know that type casting has higher precedence than addition, so it(`(GPIO_Type*)`) does not include `GPIO_MEM_SIZE`, which is an integer.

So, why it is working without any problem? Does the compiler automatically cast `GPIO_MEM_SIZE` also?

Comment: Instead of doing integer arithmetic like the first snippet, the last snippet is doing pointer arithmetic. Both are valid in C, but the results will be different. Use `printf("%p\n", (void *)GPIOB)` to see the addresses that were computed.

Comment: @user3386109 hmm, so, when `GPIO_BASE` casted to a pointer first, then adding something to it will be counted as pointer arithmetic automatically. Then, even if it does not give a warning/error, it won't work as I intended. Thanks.